# Holding event for desktop app not firing

Tags: xaml, touch, win-universal-app

In my **Universal Windows App**, I am subscribing to the **Holding event in my ListViewItem DataTemplat**e:

```
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Holding="ListViewItem_Holding">
                    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                        <MenuFlyout Placement="Right">
                            <!-- using the Click event -->
                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="delete" Click="DeleteProductClick" />

                            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="edit" />
                        </MenuFlyout>
                    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

All works well using the Visual Studio Simulator and touch mode, but I cannot find a way to **invoke the context menu using my mouse**. Do I have to use a GestureRecognizer to get the context menu to work for the desktop application (as opposed to the tablet version)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [RightTapped](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.righttapped) event instead so that the context menu shows up when user holds on an item in a touch based device and also when user right clicks with a mouse in a mouse based device:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <MenuFlyout x:Key="flyout">
     ...
   </MenuFlyout>

</Page.Resources>
...

<ListView ....>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <Grid RightTapped="grid_RightTapped">
            ...
       </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then handle the event in code behind:

```
private void grid_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e) { 
   this.flyout.ShowAt(this, e.GetPosition(this));
   e.Handled = true;
}
```

As you see I've used a shared flyout, you can go with your own way.

Answer (score 2):

From what you will find at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.holding):

> **Holding for mouse and pen/stylus input**
>
> Mouse input doesn't produce Holding events by default, no matter how long a mouse button is held down, or which button is held. However, mouse devices and some pen devices can fire RightTapped when a right mouse button or equivalent is pressed and released.
>
> Note  There is a way to treat mouse actions as hold actions if you use your own GestureRecognizer and specify HoldWithMouse in settings.

In this case you will probably have to use custom [GestureRecognizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.input.gesturerecognizer) or use *Pointer* events.