# Holding event is not fired on touch screen device

Tags: c#, uwp, touch

I'm trying to create a simple uwp app where I require to display a context menu, if user right clicks on non-touch device and if user holds on touch screen device. 
I'm using righttapped event which works perfectly on my desktop. The other side, I use holding event which should be triggered when screen is long pressed but it doesn't work(on touch screen mobile).

```
private void Webview_Holding(object sender, HoldingRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Webview.ContextFlyout.ShowAt(sender as FrameworkElement);
    }
```

Do I need to use some other event for showing context menu, if yes then which one?

Answer (score 2):

You should use RightTapped event for both touch and non-touch devices as I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995594/holding-event-for-desktop-app-not-firing/35003232#35003232). However, WebView does not support all of the touch or keyboard events.

Remarks section of MSDN for [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview) control:

> As indicated in the Events table, WebView doesn’t support most of the
>   user input events inherited from UIElement, such as KeyDown, KeyUp,
>   and PointerPressed. A common workaround is to use InvokeScriptAsync
>   with the JavaScript eval function to use the HTML event handlers, and
>   to use window.external.notify from the HTML event handler to notify
>   the application using WebView.ScriptNotify.

Comment: I know the usage of RightTapped very well and I've used it too. But as I mentioned in my question, my problem is with Holding_event which is triggered in case of touch screen devices.

Comment: @VivekVaishya You don't need the Holding event for touch screen devices. The RightTapped event just works fine on both touch and mouse-based devices. Your problem is with WebView not raising mouse/touch events at all.

Comment: I tried right tapped event and it works on desktop( that is non-touch) even with webview .But none of the other events such as holding, tapped, manipulation(all of them) are working on mobile. It could be a problem with mobile not recognizing holding event, can it be possible?

Comment: I understood what you meant to say. Do you have an example in javascript to recognize holding event ? Please elaborate it, if possible (as I'm like newbie to js).

Comment: @VivekVaishya [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909167/how-to-add-a-custom-right-click-menu-to-a-webpage) you can find an answer for showing context menu in javascript.